# error message: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Im getting INVALID COLUMN INDEX when trying to insert data in table.

This is my DAO. Not sure why there is invalid column index.

```
    try{  
            currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into lecturer (lecturerID,lecturerFullname,lecturerPassword) values'"
                    + lecturerID + "','" + lecturerFullname + "','" + lecturerPassword +"'");  
            ps.setString(1,Lbean.getLecturerID());  
            ps.setString(2,Lbean.getLecturerFullname());  
            ps.setString(3,Lbean.getLecturerPassword());  
            ps.executeUpdate();  

           }
```

Is there anything i missed??? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Learn about prepared statements.show your table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your query like this:

```
  insert into lecturer (lecturerID,lecturerFullname,lecturerPassword) values(? , ? , ?);
```

The question marks are placeholders for fixed values that you must set before executing an SQL statement.